# How to create own login form in Joomla and how to create redirect file after login

Tags: authentication, joomla

I want to create my own login form. After user login , it will redirect to the mainpage which is same page when use default login form in Joomla in template. The problem is, i want to display the page by using my own login form. not use Joomla login form in template. How to create the login form then display on Joomla template? using php? I hope you can help me. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to override the `components/com_users/views/login` view in order to modify the look and feel of the login form. Yes - you will need to know/use PHP in order to do that.

Comment: Thank you.. your answer really help me.